# php foreach returning value=>value instead of key=>value

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I have an object, when I do a var_dump this is the output:

```
array(7) {
  ["foodRaw"     ]=>  string(9) "000000000"
  ["broodRaw"    ]=>  string(9) "111000000"
  ["food"        ]=>  int(0)
  ["brood"       ]=>  int(3)
  ["size"        ]=>  int(0)
  ["foodHarvest" ]=>  int(0)
  ["broodHarvest"]=>  int(0)
}
```

When I do

```
foreach ($data AS $key => $Value){ 
    $this->{$key} = $Value;
    echo $this->{$key} . " = " . $Value . "<br>
    ";
}
```

IT doesn't behave like I expect, It ouputs this nonsense:

```
000000000 = 000000000<br>
111000000 = 111000000<br>
0 = 0<br>
3 = 3<br>
0 = 0<br>
0 = 0<br>
0 = 0<br>
```

Does anybody know the logic behind this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well sure. You are setting:

```
$this->{$key} = $Value;
```

So now those both have the same value. If you immediately echo them:

```
echo $this->{$key} . " = " . $Value
```

You'll get the same output for both! This is like setting `$a = $b` and then being surprised when `echo $a = $b` shows you the same value for both.

I think what you want is:

```
echo $key . " = " . $Value
```